# How to properly import JS modules I can use in browser?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify

I am trying to import bigdecimal, but I ran into an issue that calling

```
var bigdecimal = require('bigdecimal')
```

But in browser I am getting

```
(index):89 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I've tried multiple different approaches to this but I'm not exactly sure what to do.  I tried using requireJS and browserify and following the documentation but I'm not exactly sure what the issue is and I keep getting that require is not defined.

Comment: `require` is Common JS and not supported by browsers. You can use requireJS or browserify. Please show your approach.

Comment: There's just not enough information here